# How to list organisation private repository via GitHub API?

Tags: github, request, private

I am trying to the list the private repos of the organization using GitHub API, but I am getting only the public repository as return.

Here's the URL :
https://api.github.com/orgs/github/repos

Also I added the access token in the header, and also given the right scopes.

Here's the documentation:
https://developer.github.com/v3/

https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/#list-organizations-for-the-authenticated-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use the Github API: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories

GET /orgs/:org/repos

To access repository visibility during the preview period, you must provide a custom media type in the Accept header:

```
application/vnd.github.nebula-preview+json
```

[image]

You can also add the type parameter to control the visibility:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response bro. tried adding Accept this 'application/vnd.github.nebula-preview+json' along with the query string parameter ' type = all'. Not returning the private repo

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/vivekgoel15/GithubAPIUtility/blob/master/src/main/java/com/appdirect/rest/RestHandler.java
Although it's in java, but might help you to pass token and data to github server

Comment: Thanks for your response bro. I'm just done a mistake in url path. now its working fine.